# How do we handle questions with provably wrong assumption given as incidental info?

Tags: discussion, questions

Related Question: [How do we handle questions based on incorrect premise?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/how-do-we-handle-questions-based-on-incorrect-premise)

Unlike the premise explored in the linked question - how do we handle a question where the question is completely valid, yet includes an incorrect bit of information (which makes no difference to the actual question or its answers)

Eg. [Is the Teen Titans Robin Tim Drake or Dick Grayson?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29426/is-the-teen-titans-robin-tim-drake-or-dick-grayson)
This is a perfectly fine question, with a perfectly fine answer. However, the question includes the incorrect assumption that the Teen Titans animated series is part of the Timm/Diniverse continuity - an assumption which is not challenged by the highest voted and accepted answers.

In such a case is it ok to go ahead and edit/remove the part of the question which gives the incorrect premise or is it better to just comment to the question with the correct info?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In cases like these I usually just leave a comment with the correct information and a "You might want to edit your post" nudge. I personally do not feel comfortable editing someone else's question or answer to the point that the edits change the essence of the Q or A. Also, you could actually answer the question and include a correction of the wrong info there.

Comment: I usually just edit out the wrong assumption. The OP can always roll it back if they want to put the wrong info back into their question...

Answer (score 5):

If the incorrect information makes no difference to the question or any of it's answers, then editing the question to remove the information won't materially alter it, and so it's OK to edit the question.

If the incorrect information does make a difference then stating that the question is based on an invalid premise in an answer is OK: it's a valid way of answering the question.